setState unexpectedly called when onChange event happens
First post on StackOverflow. It is nice to meet you!
I am trying to implement a simple monolithic application from a React book and I am stumbling on a behaviour I can't explain. I would like to ask your help understanding why this is happening. The example is of a poorly designed application, which will later be broken down into reusable components.
When I type any character in the input field "Title", the onChangeTitle event is called as expected. But after the event is executed, the useState for "articles" (at the top of the MyFeature() function definition) is also called, effectively executing the "id" function again and again, every time a character is typed in the "Title" input field.
I have debugged the code and it seems that the execution goes to the top of "MyFeature" and moves down the setState calls, but only the state for "articles" and "title" change. I was expecting the entire MyFeature to be rerendered, but I was not expecting the "articles" setState hook to be called, as there was no change to its value. Any idea why this might be happening?
Thank you for your help!
Marco
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

const id = (function* () {
    let i = 1;
    while (true) {
    console.log(i);
    yield i;
    i += 1;
    }
  })();

function MyFeature() {
    const [articles, setArticles] = useState(
        [
            {
                id: id.next(),
                title: "Article 1",
                summary: "Article 1 summary",
                display: "none"
            },
            {
                id: id.next(),
                title: "Article 2",
                summary: "Article 2 summary",
                display: "none"
            }
        ]
    );
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [summary, setSummary] = useState("");

    const onChangeTitle = useCallback((e) => {
        setTitle(e.target.value);
      }, []);

      const onChangeSummary = useCallback((e) => {
        setSummary(e.target.value);
      }, []);

      const onClickAdd = useCallback(() => {
        setArticles((state) => [
          ...state,
          {
            id: id.next(),
            title: title,
            summary: summary,
            display: "none",
          },
        ]);
        setTitle("");
        setSummary("");
      }, [summary, title]);

      const onClickRemove = useCallback((id) => {
        setArticles((state) => state.filter((article) => article.id !== id));
      }, []);
    
      const onClickToggle = useCallback((id) => {
        setArticles((state) => {
          const articles = [...state];
          const index = articles.findIndex((article) => article.id === id);
    
          articles[index] = {
            ...articles[index],
            display: articles[index].display ? "" : "none",
          };
    
          return articles;
        });
      }, []);

    return(
        <section>
            <header>
                <h1>Articles</h1>
                <input placeholder="Title" value={title} onChange={onChangeTitle} />
                <input placeholder="Summary" value={summary} onChange={onChangeSummary} />
                <button onClick={onClickAdd}>Add</button>
            </header>
            <article>
                <ul>
                    {articles.map((i) => (
                        <li key={i.id.value}>
                            <a href={'#${i.id}'} title="Toggle Summary" onClick={() => onClickToggle(i.id)}>{i.title}</a>
                            &nbsp;
                            <button href={'#${i.id}'} title="Remove" onClick={() => onClickRemove(i.id)}>&#10007;</button>
                            <p style={{ display: i.display }}>{i.summary}</p>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </article>
        </section>
    );
}

export default MyFeature;


On every re-render, the code for your function will be run, so there's no way that the expression used in the useState initializer wouldn't be executed. That would be contrary to how JavaScript functions work; the expression will always be evaluated, even though the result of that expression is ignored since the articles state is already initialized.
The useState hook does have a variation that lets you specify a function instead of a value that will ensure that the initialization expression is only evaluated once, when the state is initialized.
const [articles, setArticles] = useState(() => [
  {
    id: id.next(),
    title: "Article 1",
    summary: "Article 1 summary",
    display: "none"
  },
  {
    id: id.next(),
    title: "Article 2",
    summary: "Article 2 summary",
    display: "none"
  }
]);

If you use that, then it won't run id.next() more than the twice on the first-time render.
